# What does a not a statement mean?

Tags: java

```
Pane pane = new Pane();
String str = new String("Welcome To Java");
String[] ary = str.split("");


for(int i =0; i<=str.length(); i++){
    int x = 50;
    int y = 100;
    int r = 3;
    Text text2 = new Text(x,y, ary[i]);
    text2.setRotate(r);
    pane.getChildren().add(text2);
    x+10;
    y+5;
    r+3;
}


Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.setMinWidth(200);
primaryStage.setMinHeight(200);
primaryStage.setResizable(true);
primaryStage.setTitle("Welcome To Java");
primaryStage.show();
```

I'm trying to change the coordinate for every character in the array every loop, but this gives me a "not a statement error" at `x+10`, `y+5` and `r+3`.

Comment: In effect, it means those lines don't do anything. They return a value, but don't do anything with it. Your program would be identical if those lines didn't exist.

Comment: also you have to declare x,y.. outside of the loop

Comment: In addition you can use x=x+10; instead of x+10;

Comment: You should actually assign the outcome of 'x+10' to something 'x = x + 10' for example. Also you iterate from 0 to <= str.length(). This is one field too far.

Comment: ok , i tried declaring x,y outside the loop.
whats wrong with 0 to <=str.length() ?

edit : after i tried it , it compiles, but still gives me an exception error

Answer (score 2):

The statements must complete as they need to resolve as a expression.

Valid statements will be

```
    x= x+10;
    y= y+5;
    r= r+3;
```

And it seems your logic is broken, as the increments are  happening in each iteration. Declare them outside the loop will get the desired output.